# Php version reads as one version, when I need another

Tags: php, bash, macos, laravel, terminal

On mac/terminal, I'm attempting to set up a local server with laravel but keep getting error that the php version is not up to date. I have attempted to install the needed 5.6 version via this tutorial, but I'm assuming it needs to be updated in my bash, possibly all things that are using it like Composer. I am not certain how to update the bash correctly or really what to do from here. https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-php-on-osx/ is how I updated. Also, if you have any suggestions as to what I can be learning to prevent this question in the future that would be much appreciated/where to start. EDIT:   error: This package requires php >=5.6.4 but your PHP version (5.5.36) does not satisfy that requirement. terminal command: composer update

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: command is 'composer update' error is This package requires php >=5.6.4 but your PHP version (5.5.36) does not satisfy that requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install php from homebrew

`brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
brew unlink php56
brew install php70`see if it works for you. I had to alias to php7 in my ~/.bash_profile

Comment: seemed to be working, allowed me to update composer, but now it is showing the php version at 5.5 again and throws : 

Parse error: parse error, expecting `'&'' or `"variable (T_VARIABLE)"' in /Users/BKorenek/Desktop/Laravel/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 475

Comment: Okay, rebuilt project reran all of the updates and it seems to be working great! Reading out correct php version and  everything.